# objective-c divide always returns 0

Tags: objective-c, operations, divide

Something really weird is happening.

```
float p1 = (6 / 100);
NSLog(@"p1 = %f", p1);
```

With those two lines of code I get the following output:

p1 = 0.000000

Why is a simple devide with static numbers not working! I have so much work to do to deal with divide not working! What he heck, am I crazy?

Answer (score 34):

Those constants are integers, so the math is done with integer math. Try

```
float p1 = (6.0 / 100.0);
```

*edit* — @Stephen Canon wisely points out that since "p1" is a `float`, there's no reason not to do the whole computation as `float`:

```
float p1 = (6.0f / 100.0f);
```

Now, since those things are both constants, I'd imagine there's a really good chance that the work is going to be done by the compiler anyway. It's also true that because on some modern machines (ie, Intel architecture), the floating-point processor instruction set is sufficiently weird that something that seems like an obvious "optimization" may or may not work out that way. Finally I suppose it *might* be the case that doing the operation with `float` constants could (in some cases) give a different result that doing the operation with `double` values and then casting to `float`, which if true would probably be the best argument for deciding one way or the other.

Comment: You should actually accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: But use single-precision literals to avoid an unnecessary conversion from double to single: `float p1 = 6.0f / 100.0f`

Answer (score 12):

Since both of these numbers are considered to be integers by the computer, integer math is performed and an integer is returned with no decimals which is 0 (0.06), then converted to float and stored in the variable p1.

A least one number (or both) has to be float to do floating point math, when you append a decimal to a number you tell the computer that the constant is a floating point number.

```
float p1 = (6.0 / 100);
```

Or you could typecast it

```
float p1 = ((float)6 / 100);
```

Answer (score 9):

Your assignment contains an integer divide, which returns zero if the number you are dividing by is greater. You probably meant to do:

```
float p1 = (6.0f / 100.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

A work around to divide two int variables and get float result.

```
int x = 5;
int y = 7;

float z = x / y;  // always 0
```

**The fix**:

```
float z = 1.0 * x / y;
```

**Note:** if you change the order this solution won't work.

**Edit:**
According to this answer [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702536/objective-c-divide-always-returns-0/31044013#3702642) You can use this

```
float z = (float) x / y;
```